# How to connect to localhost:5555 from another computer?

Tags: localhost, chat

I am building a chat app and it runs on localhost port 5555 but when it gets run on another machine it says the target machine actively refused connection. How do I make the other computer connect to my 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` is your local host - you're telling your computer to "look for what's on part 5555 on this very machine"

another machine that has nothing on port 5555 won't work!

If the other machine is on your local network, you may be able to set up port forwarding in your router. Otherwise, what you're basically looking for is a web server: something to serve websites! For that, we can't really answer the question without knowing how you're building it. Is it command-line? Django? React?

Comment: its a command line chat app I do not know how to  set the port equal to a url

Comment: Google for "port forwarding" + your router brand to get instructions on how to set it up - it varies by router.